# How to send __RequestVerificationToken when using $http angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to send `__RequestVerificationToken` when using $http angular?
Automatically add `__RequestVerificationToken` to data in posted data.

```
app.factory('LoginRepository', function ($http) {
    return {
        Login: function (lg) {
            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Account/Login',
                data: {
                    Username: lg.Username,
                    Password: lg.Username,
                    RememberMe: lg.Username,
                },
            }

            return $http(req);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to add __RequestVerificationToken into the header of request ? If yes then you can use interceptors

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptorService');

});
```

InterceptorService itself will be a factory/service :

```
app.factory('InterceptorService ', ['localStorageService', function (localStorageService) {

var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

var _request = function (config) {

    config.headers = config.headers || {};

    var authData = localStorageService.get('token');

    if (authData) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
    }

    return config;

}}
```

Comment: you can use config.data instead of config.headers